# Computer gets hot with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, overheating

So recently I had installed Linux Mint (Rosa) on computer and I dual boot it with windows 10. With windows there is no problem, it does not get hot for example if I get into YouTube or something not CPU intensive.

But in Linux Mint which takes 52GB of total 500GB of C: Disk (The only PC DISK) even if I open Firefox it will start to get hot. Checking through a program I see that CPU, RAM, and disk are reaching 60-70 Celsius.

PC model is:**HP 2000-2D02SV NOTEBOOK PC**. PC is really clean inside and 
I also did check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/588109/laptop-gets-hot-when-using-linux-mint).

I want to use Linux but if I open something like Blender it will be burned in 30-60 seconds.

Comment: I imagine there is a process that is hogging the CPU.

Comment: Run `top` or a similar program to see what is consuming CPU time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `top` doesn't show any CPU consuming processes running, it may have happened that the processor throttling is poorly configured, making all the CPU cores run at maximum MHz. In this case, installing `indicator-cpufreq` may help.

Comment: Searhing i found that Windows is configuring at real time the cpu so it doesn't run at maximum frequency so that might be the answer..thanks,i will try it.!

Comment: That's interesting since I've read that optimal configuration means maximum frequency at load and minimum frequency on idle. This is the case on my Ubuntu system. In fact, the cpu is said to change even into a hibernate state on idle. In the end, this is said to be the most power saving configuration (and thus the coolest). So Windows might not be configured to be cool!?

Comment: Windows seems to have a driver which is controlling cpu frequency which Linux Mint has not by default.Installing this (indicator-cpufreq) it seems that the problem is solved.I can control cpu frequency between power save mode and performance mode.